# Odometry calibration for Create

Tags: ros, navigation, odometry, calibration, create-autonomy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Using ROS Indigo and the create_autonomy package I'm able to control an iRobot Create 2. I would like to calibrate the odometry using a method similar to that used for the [Turtlebot](http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot_calibration/Tutorials/Calibrate%20Odometry%20and%20Gyro) - or simpler. Just by moving manually a certain distance and measuring with a measuring tape the robot distance to obtain a correction factor that can then be incorporated into the driver to improve accuracy. Same for angular correction.
I'm aware of http://answers.ros.org/question/232529/moving-base-set-distance-without-navigation-stack/  but would rather measure and enter a linear and angular calibration correction factor for a given floor type that takes care of any inconsistencies. Any help or insight would be appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/239192/odometry-calibration-for-create/) by [ras_cal](https://answers.ros.org/users/27002/ras_cal/) on ROS Answers with karma: 40 on 2016-07-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From what I can tell, *turtlebot_calibration* is making use of an active 3D sensor to calibrate angular measurements. I'm not familiar with odometry calibration, but you could start by looking at [turtlebot_calibration](https://github.com/turtlebot/turtlebot_apps/tree/indigo/turtlebot_calibration). You might be able to adapt their code by replacing the scan delta with manual user input for comparison against the odometry. Also, to keep things simple, keep angular calibration separate from linear calibration.

I'd be more than happy to review and integrate any solution you come up with into the package [ca_tools](https://github.com/AutonomyLab/create_autonomy/tree/indigo-devel/ca_tools).

---

Originally posted by [jacobperron](https://answers.ros.org/users/26373/jacobperron/) with karma: 1870 on 2016-07-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1